# Jar not working with external resources

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I tried to export my application that **works fine** when running on eclipse but not for its jar file.

My external resource is an xls file in `\src\resources` folder.
And my main function is in: `\src\sau\se\fill`

**Main:**

```
public class SSFillerMain {
    private static StationSecondaireService ssService;
    private static SecondaryStationFiller fill; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ssService = new StationSecondaireServiceImpl();
        int sheetNumber = 0;
        int colsNumber = 13;
        int rowsNumber = 22223;

        fill = new SecondaryStationFiller(sheetNumber,
                colsNumber, rowsNumber);
//staff
}
```

**SecondaryStationFiller:**

```
public SecondaryStationFiller(int sheet, int cols, int rows) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hi 1");
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/ss.xls");

        File f = null;
        try {
            f = new File(url.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            f = new File(url.getPath());
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hi 3");
        this.excelHandler = new ExcelHandler(f, sheet, cols, rows);
    }
```

What i have is that i can not see the message: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hi 3");`, so that's mean that the problem is in `url` parameter, is there anything missing?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168266/accessing-a-resource-within-a-jar-working-in-netbeans-but-not-on-command-line?rq=1

Comment: i have to work with jre6 and i am quite sure that the problem is `toUri()` funtcion

Comment: So I assume you don't get any exceptions and the URL is not null. Have you tried to print the "content" of the actual URL? It should be something like: `file:///path/to/your/jarFile.jar!/resources/ss.xls"`

Comment: @RomanVottner yeah i have printed it and it is as you worte.. is that correct?

Comment: So the file should be at the right place - why don't you try to access your file with `url.getPath()` if `url.toURI()` causes problems?

Comment: @RomanVottner it has gave me nothing, when i printed `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, f.exists());` it showed me `false`

Comment: can you try to comment out the `JOptionPane` and instead do a `System.out.println(...)`? Just to test if the error is with the file loading or the JOptinPane as there are a couple of reports that the OptionPane didn't show up for some reasons

Comment: My problem is with the jar not with eclipse: ) so Println does not give any thing with jar