# In netbeans, how to save or access an image after deploying jar file

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to make a mess management application in Java using NetBeans. I want to save images of Members in a specified folder inside my `src` directory. I just created folder named EmpImgs for storing employees images. Here is my code:

```
File srcDir = new File(file);    // current path of image     
File dstDir = new File("src\\J_Mess_Mgnt\\EmpImgs\\"+Txt_C_G_M_M_ID.getText());
objm.copyFile(srcDir, dstDir);`  // copy image from srcDir to dstDir
```

Here I use another class for copying images to predefined folders and renaming the images based on their ID.

Everything is working properly in Java IDE.

But unfortunately after making an executable .jar file, this code will not work. I cannot save or access any image file in that directory.

I just went through this site, but I didn't find a suitable answer.

**All I need is saving and editing images inside jar folder**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a resource within a jar (working in Netbeans but not on command line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168266/accessing-a-resource-within-a-jar-working-in-netbeans-but-not-on-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hehe hi mate you need some help. This is a duplicate but I will cut you some slack and maybe you should delete this later. So back to basics, the jvm runs byte code, which you get from compiling java source code to .class files. Now this is different to C and C++ were you just get a .exe. You don't want to give your users a bunch of .class files in all these folders which they can edit and must run a command on the command line, but instead give them what is known as an 'archive' which is just an imutable file structure so they can't screw up the application, known as a jar in java. They can just double click on the archive (which is a jar), and the jvm will call the main method specified in the MetaInf directory (just some information about the jar, same as a manifest in other programming languages).

Now remember your application is now a jar! It is immutable! for the resasons I explained. You can't save anymore data there! Your program will still work on the command line and in IDEs because it is working as if you used your application is distrubuted as bunch of folders with the .class files, and you can write to this location.

If you want to package resources with your application you need to use streams (google it). BUT REMEMBER! you cant then save more resources into the jar! You need to write somewhere else! Maybe use a user.home directory! or a location specified from the class path and the photos will be right next to the jar! Sometimes you might need an installer for your java application, but usually you don't want to create the extra work if you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you sir,Thanks for giving me this valuable information.I think its better to create a folder outside the jar folder. using some commands,right.Let me try.and anybody who have some extra idea or knowledge or information about my topic Please give me a brief,Thanks in advance,

Comment: No worries, I dunno what the best way is to go about learning all this stuff, it kind of comes with experience I guess so if you just keep at it you'll learn it. I would 1st suggest to find the balance between doing general learning, like following these tutorials http://www.newthinktank.com/videos/java-video-tutorial/ and looking for specific answers to questions because often you don't know that the right question is when your starting out.

Comment: ok sir.I am not an experienced person.So I expect your sincere help and suggestion for my  questions.,Regards,,

Answer (score 0):

At last I find an answer suit for my question.It is not possible to copy images or files to a executive jar folder.So I used a different Idea.Create some folders(as per our requirement),Where my executable jar folder is located(No matter which drive or where the location is).The code is..

```
String PRJT_PATH="";          //variable to store path of working directory.

private void getdire() throws IOException{
    File f=new File(".");
    File[] f1=f.listFiles();
    PRJT_PATH=f.getCanonicalPath();  //get path details.for eg:-E:/java/dist

}
private void new_Doc_folder(){  //function for creating new folders
try{
    String strManyDirectories="Docs"+File.separator+"Bil_Img";   //i need to  create 2 folders,1st a folder namedDocs and In Docs folder another folder named Bil_Img 

   String SubDirectories="Docs"+File.separator+"EmpImgs";  //same as above but keep in mind that It will not create a Same folder again if already exists,
    // Create one directory

    boolean success = (new File(strManyDirectories)).mkdirs(); //create more than one directory
    boolean success1 = (new File(SubDirectories)).mkdir();    //Creates a single directory
        if (success && success1) {
        }    

}catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

It works Successfully.

Regds